# Are multiple aggregates in a select statement a performance concern?

Tags: mysql

Considering the simple statement below, I am using the SUM and COUNT values in a customer table but I also want to use the values to calculate a third column, average_sale.

I instantly tried to just use the column aliases which would 'appear' to be clearer however I had to use the SUM and COUNT again.

Is this performant?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(payments.amount) as total_sales, 
    COUNT(payments.id) as quantity, 
    SUM(payments.amount) / COUNT(payments.id) as average_sale, 
    `users`.`name`, 
    `payments`.`user_id` 
FROM `payments` 
INNER JOIN `users` on `payments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
GROUP BY `payments`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY `total_sales` DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried to compare `EXPLAIN` on both queries to see if the result changes?

Comment: Select sum and count or select sum, count and sum/count s sthe pratically the same for performance  .. and remember you can't use alias for alias_Sum/alias_count ..

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? 5.x or 8.x?

Answer (score 1):

As a general answer I would say, no. However, **only a SQL execution plan will tell**.

In your case you are reusing the same aggregation expressions multiple times. Even a basic SQL optimizer should realize they are the same ones and will compute each one a single time.

Since your query does not have filtering conditions, it's reading both tables whole. The biggest cost of your query is probably related to the join order. Should it start by `payments` and then walk to `users`, or vice versa? The presence/abscence of indexes can be decisive here.

**Edit:**

Now, if you find out your optimizer is not that clever, you can make sure it computes each aggregation only once by using a subquery (or a CTE if using MySQL 8.x). For example, you could rephrase your query as:

```
select 
  total_sales,
  quantity,
  total_sales / quantity as average_sale, 
  `name`,
  `user_id`
from (
  SELECT 
    SUM(payments.amount) as total_sales, 
    COUNT(payments.id) as quantity, 
    `users`.`name`, 
    `payments`.`user_id` 
  FROM `payments` 
  INNER JOIN `users` on `payments`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
  GROUP BY `payments`.`user_id` 
) x
ORDER BY `total_sales` DESC
```

Comment: "In your case you are reusing the same aggregation expressions multiple times. Even a basic SQL optimizer should realize they are the same ones and will compute each one a single time." - At least for my version it's not the case. And EXPLAIN doesn't show the difference.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Duly noted. The extra edit solution could make a difference if the optimizer doesn't realize it needs to compute the aggregations only once.